# Rails 6 - Nokogiri LoadError conflict between development and production (x86_64-darwin & x86_64-linux)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, nokogiri, darwin

When I try deploy using `capistrano` gem I get:

```
rake stderr: rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri
```

In my `Gemfile.lock` I can see that `nokogiri` is installed `nokogiri (1.11.2-x86_64-darwin)` which is for mac since I'm using mac for development, and when I do `gem list` in my production which is `ubuntu` I see `nokogiri (1.11.2 x86_64-linux)`.

Based on one of the answers on SO, I removed `-x86_64-darwin` from `nokogiri (1.11.2-x86_64-darwin)` but this gave me:

```
Downloading nokogiri-1.11.2 revealed dependencies not in the API or the lockfile (mini_portile2 (~> 2.5.0)).
Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update nokogiri` should fix the problem.
```

I ran `bundle update nokogiri` with no luck and it only said: `Bundler attempted to update nokogiri but its version stayed the same`.

I know this issue *might* happen since the `nokogiri` in my local is for mac and for development is for Linux.

I'm not sure what I can do to resolve this issue. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
Rails: 6.1.3
Ruby: 2.5.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced a similar problem and [this](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#how-can-i-avoid-using-a-precompiled-native-gem) helped me.